# Getting 500 from EWS API

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to exchange web server APIs from java. I want to configure the mail flow rules. This is the code I am using -

```java
exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
exchangeService.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/exchange.asmx"));
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
this.exchangeService.setCredentials(credentials);
exchangeService.getInboxRules();
```

The account I'm trying to connect to is a trial account with a domain like - <org_name>.onmicrosoft.com. The credentials are fetched from the graph API oauth flow. I am using this library - https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/tree/master

I get a 500 error as response with this text - `The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.`

Is there something wrong with my approach or some documentation I can't seem to be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

If by Mail Flow rules you mean the transport Rules eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rules then EWS isn't the correct API to use. EWS will let you modify the Inbox rules for each user (so will the Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http which is a better approach if this is what you are trying to achieve). The only method of modifying the Mail Flow transport rules would be to use the exov3 cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-transportrule?view=exchange-ps.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to do these steps for solving your error 500

1. Check your error log on log file, when the log file was available on your environtment. Do fixing as soon as you can.
2. Remove your cache & cookies after you fix any issue.
3. Make sure server was running or at least can receive ping from your any device